# Jquery with update panel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have web application where i'm using gridview with updatepanel, after updating the `gridview` I called jQuery function (at the end of `GridView1_RowUpdating`)

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myfunction", "$(document).ready(function(){_success()});", true);
```

The success function is

```
function _success() {
    $('#success').slideDown();
}
```

where the success div is inside the updatepanel. Still I'm not able to show the message.

Comment: Have you checked the resulting HTML to see if this line shows up? `$(document).ready(function(){_success()});`  Are you getting any errors in the JS console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this Issue by using the Hiddenvalue as mentioned in this Link
http://zeemalik.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/how-to-call-client-side-javascript-function-after-an-updatepanel-asychronous-ajax-request-is-over/